# How to Display Enclosed Aphanumeric (⒮, ①) in PDFKIT or convert to Normal Alphanumeric string

Tags: javascript, unicode, pdf-generation, pdfkit, alphanumeric

I'm using PDFKIT to generate PDF on Node JS.
However, enclosed alphanumeric (such as ⒮, ①, etc.) couldn't be generate.

I checked on [Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+JP), and it seems that NotoSansCJKjp-Regular supports enclosed alphanumeric. So I think that it might be this library doesn't support enclosed alphanumeric.

Is there any I could generate enclosed alphanumeric on PDF or
is there ways I could convert it to regular alphanumeric?

For example, ⒮ => (s), ① => 1

Appreciate all your helps!

Below is my code.

```
export class CreateVoucherUsecase {
  private doc = new PDFDocument({ size: 'A4', margin: 20 });

  async createAirTicketVoucher(res: Response, id: number): Promise<void> {
    const hotel = await new AirTicketRepository().findById(id);
    if (hotel === null) throw new NotFoundError('airticket voucher pdf: airticket not found: id = ' + id);
    this.setFontRegular();
    this.writeInfo(res, info);
    this.doc.end();
  }

  private drawHorizontalLine(params: { length: number; color?: string; width?: number; dy?: number }): void {
    this.doc
      .moveTo(this.doc.x, this.doc.y + (params.dy ?? 0))
      .lineWidth(params.width ?? 1)
      .lineTo(this.doc.x + params.length, this.doc.y + (params.dy ?? 0))
      .stroke(params.color ?? 'blue');
  }

  private getAsset(path: string): string {
    return require.main?.path.replace('dist', path) ?? '';
  }

  private setFont(style: string): void {
    this.doc.font(this.getAsset(`fonts/NotoSansCJKjp-${style}.ttf`));
  }
  private setFontRegular(): void {
    this.setFont('Regular');
  }
  private setFontBold(): void {
    this.setFont('Bold');
    this.doc.fontSize(12);
  }

  /** write text. not update indent */
  private text(value: string, x?: number, y?: number) {
    const originalX = this.doc.x;
    return this.doc.text(value, x, y).text('', originalX);
  }

  private writeH2(text: string): void {
    this.setFontBold();
    this.doc
      .moveDown()
      .fillColor('black')
      .text(text, undefined, this.doc.y + 10);
    this.setFontRegular();
  }

  private writeLink(link: string, length: number): void {
    this.doc.fillColor('blue').text(link);
    this.drawHorizontalLine({ length: length, dy: SPACE });
  }

  private writeTable(labels: string[], values: (string | number)[]): void {
    const tableWidth = 480;
    const column1Width = 150;
    const marginLeft = 3;
    for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      const [leftTopX, leftTopY] = [this.doc.x, this.doc.y];
      this.text(labels[i], leftTopX + marginLeft);
      const [newX, newY] = [this.doc.x, this.doc.y];
      this.text(convert2String(values[i].toString()), leftTopX + column1Width + marginLeft, leftTopY);
      this.text('', newX, newY); 
      const [rectX, rectY, rectHeight] = [leftTopX, leftTopY + SPACE, this.doc.y - leftTopY];
      if (i < labels.length)
        this.doc
          .lineWidth(1)
          .rect(rectX, rectY, tableWidth, rectHeight)
          .stroke('black')
          .rect(rectX, rectY, column1Width, rectHeight)
          .fillOpacity(0.2)
          .fillAndStroke('#AFEEEE', 'black')
          .fillOpacity(1)
          .fillColor('black');
    }
  }

  private writeInfo(res: Response, info: Info): void {
   ...........
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to apply [Unicode normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). For instance, in Python `import unicodedata; [{form: unicodedata.normalize( form, '⒮①')}  for form in ['NFC','NFKC','NFD','NFKD']]` returns `[{'NFC': '⒮①'}, {'NFKC': '(s)1'}, {'NFD': '⒮①'}, {'NFKD': '(s)1'}]` (sorry, I can't use JavaScript just now).

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved when I use the following [normalization method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize).

```
String.normalize('NFKC')
```